# Q: make vuex store globally available with Vue 3 and typescript (project built with the cli) +solved

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuex4

How do I make my store globally available in vue 3 with vuex?

My store:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  getters: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
})
```

My main.ts

```
import yourStore from './store/yourStore'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(yourStore)

app.config.globalProperties.$yourStore = yourStore

app.mount('#app')
```

This doesn't work:

```
this.$yourStore.dispatch('your action')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the store to shims-vuex.d.ts to make it globally available, like this:

```
import { yourStore } from './store/yourStore' // path to store file

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $yourStore: yourStore
  }
}
```

Now this works

```
this.$yourStore.dispatch('your action')
```